# Convert DateTime string in elapsed time in a Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a static `html` `<table>` like this which I cannot modify:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Street\Art</td>
        <td>Start</td>
        <td>10.06.2014 21:59:40</td>
        <td>10.06.2014 22:00:29</td>
        <td>0.0.0.0.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Street\Art</td>
        <td>Updated</td>
        <td>KABIT</td>
        <td>10.06.2014 22:00:44</td>
        <td>0.0.0.0.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Street\Art</td>
        <td>Down</td>
        <td>10.06.2014 22:02:54</td>
        <td>10.06.2014 22:03:43</td>
        <td>0.0.0.0.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cloud\Art</td>
        <td>Start</td>
        <td>11.06.2014 18:23:42</td>
        <td>11.06.2014 18:24:38</td>
        <td>1.1.1.1.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cloud\Art</td>
        <td>Updated</td>
        <td>JEL_EM</td>
        <td>11.06.2014 18:25:30</td>
        <td>1.1.1.1.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cloud\Art</td>
        <td>Updated</td>
        <td>JEL_EM</td>
        <td>12.06.2014 06:00:12</td>
        <td>1.1.1.1.1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to convert the **fourth** `<td>` in elapsed time.

eg:

```
<tr>
        <td>Street\Art</td>
        <td>Start</td>
        <td>10.06.2014 21:59:40</td>
        <td>10.06.2014 22:00:29 - 20 minutes ago</td>
        <td>0.0.0.0.0</td>
</tr>
```

or if its better:

```
<tr>
        <td>Street\Art</td>
        <td>Start</td>
        <td>10.06.2014 21:59:40</td>
        <td>10.06.2014 22:00:29</td>
        <td>20 minutes ago</td>
        <td>0.0.0.0.0</td>
</tr>
```

I have implemented de conversion algorithm, but I need to get the fourth `<td>` and add the elapsed time.

**My working JS-Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/LinkJoe/5UHuU/

Comment: Post your JS code over here as well..

Answer (score 0):

Try **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**.

```
$("table td:nth-child(4)").text(timeSince(new Date()));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5UHuU/2/)**

Comment: It gives always 26 mins, can you get the exact Date Time instead of fix coded DateTime `new Date('2014-06-12T08:35:00')`

Comment: JS fiddle is down..Cannot proceed! Can you post you code in JSBin

Answer (score 0):

Don't implement the time calculation algorithm from scratch. Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) library (or any other similar library) to calculate date display. Code snippet to do this is shown below. Input date can be in different formats - moment.js can parse the date in pretty much any format. Please see moment.js documentation for more information.

```
$("table td:nth-child(4)").text(moment('2014-06-12T08:35:00').fromNow());
```

Answer (score 0):

$("table tbody tr td:nth-child(3)").text("Your Text")

This should work for your. Of course, you need to modify the above , but the selector will work